# Input to amplifier with LPF not working

Tags: amplifier, low-pass

I am trying to build a pink noise machine to use at work.  See  schematic below.  If I connect the output from the MM5837N (noise generator), directly to the amp circuit.  It works fine, and is nice and loud.  However, when I include the passive LPF as shown from the example, no sound comes out. Using a scope, Fig. 1 shows the output from the MM5837 w/o the LPF.  Voltage is around 4V.  Figure 2 shows the output after the LPF.  The signal is around 2V.  At this point, the output from the LPF is not connected to the amp input.  When I do connect the output to the amp input and probe at the same point, the signal drops to around .2V, and there is no output from the amp.  Scope shows a flat-line on the amp output.  I am not an EE, so don't understand what is going on here. Do I need some kind of a buffer op-amp between the two? Any help is appreciated!  Also the LPF cap is just a ceramic type, if it matters. [Link to the amp data sheet.](http://www.nteinc.com/specs/800to899/pdf/nte823.pdf)

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You show a range of values for your LPF. If R=10k and C=0.2 uF, then the cutoff frequency of your filter is about 80 Hz.  Most of the energy generated by your noise source is well above that frequency.  If you set R=1k and C=0.02 Uf, then the cutoff frequency rises to about 16 kHz and you should see a considerably larger signal. Also your 10k pot will load the output of the LPF and also reduce the available signal.